# How to end a statement in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, conditional-operator, line-endings

I have code like

```
word.include?("test") ? @test = word : #do nothing
```

My issue is that rails expects something after the colon and treats the next line of code as if it's part of the conditional statement above.  I know I can use a regular if end statement but was curious to know if it's possible to end the statement after the colon and before reaching a new line?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You might consider something like this:

```
@test = word if word.include?("test")
```

Comment: that's a nice alternative thanks, am still hoping if anyone can tell me if it's possible to end the line just so I can learn. Thanks again